# Express HTTPS - unable to connect securely- SSLv3 broken protocol

Tags: node.js, express, https

Trying to make HTTPS server work on Express 4, however, there's an SSLv3 security error coming (please see the image). To my understanding SSLv3 protocol is not supported by browsers anymore due to POODLE attack.

How to make HTTPS server use the TLS1.2 protocol?

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
fs = require('fs'),
https = require('https'),
key = fs.readFileSync('/usr/local/etc/ssl/key.pem'),
cert = fs.readFileSync('/usr/local/etc/ssl/cert.pem'),
https_options = {
    key: key,
    cert: cert
},
PORT = 8000,
HOST = 'localhost';

https.createServer(https_options.key, app).listen(PORT);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.send('Hello');
});

module.exports = app;
```

The server is listening localhost:8000

[image: Results this]

The error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to create server like that

it is working fine at my side,

```
var server = require('https').createServer(options, app),
server.listen(port);
```

or if like to add socket

```
var server = require('https').createServer(options, app),
io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
server.listen(port);
```